# Android finding position on a map

Tags: android, dictionary, navigation, gps, coordinates

Here is my scenario:

I have an image which is a map. I use it as a background image.

The image is not square in shape. Its more like a trapezium.

I have the geo coordinates of each of the four corners of the image and the width and height of the image.

Now when I get a location coordinates from the gps, I want to be able to plot the point on the map. Since the image is not squared in shape, I cannot use simple ratio to evaluate the position of the gps coordinates on the map.

How can I plot the coordinates that I get from the gps to a location on the map?

Update:

I am using a custom map and I am not using the MapView since I can only use google maps with this view (as far as I know). Also, the application needs to be able to run offline, which I dont think is possible while using MapView (again as far as I know).

Comment: It sounds like you are not using a MapActivity, is that correct?

Comment: John, I updated the post. No I am not using the mapactivity.

Comment: Since you are using a trapezium, does this include some sort of 3D perspective?  And if so, are you using the opengles capabilities to transform your map (hopefully rectangular) into the trapezium?

Comment: No. You got the wrong idea. The map I am using is a 2d map (just width and height, no depth). Just like the 2d version of google maps (top view). But it is a map which covers a small area, and from the top view the area has a skewed square/trapezium shape. Actually, the bottom width is a little bit longer than the top width.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399453/how-to-plot-a-gps-location-on-an-image-being-used-as-a-map/15416154#15416154

Answer (score 0):

My approach, for what its worth, is that you should display your complete map in the display and fit it as best you can to the screen coordinates, so in your case, the bottom width might fit across the bottom of the display while the top would be narrower with perhaps some 'non-mapped' areas to the left and right-hand sides of the screen. You need to be able to translate the maps geo-coordinates to the screen pixel coordinates (for a relatively small area, a linear translation may be accurate enough). Then you can place a marker representing the user's location on top of the image, using the same geo-coordinates-to-pixel translation. if you want the user to be able to drag the map image in any direction or zoom in and out, then you need to adjust your screen pixel to coordinate calculation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no perspective and you have the coordinates of the four corners, its just a matter of scaling the position as follows:

```
Point upperRightGPS; // upper right GPS coordinates
Point upperLeftGPS; // upper left GPS coordinates
Point lowerRightGPS; // lower left GPS corrdinates
Point upperRight; // upper right screen pixel value (100, 0)?
Point upperLeft; // upper left screen pixel value (0,0)?
Point lowerRight; // lower right screen pixel value (0, 200)?

public Point positionOnMap(Point gps){

    double dx = (upperRight.x - upperLeft.x)/(upperRightGPS.x - upperLeftGPS.x);
    double dy = (upperRight.y - lowerRight.y)/(upperRightGPS.y - lowerRightGPS.y);

    return new Point((int) dx * gps.x, (int) dy * gps.y);
}
```

This assumes that the origin is in the upperleft of your screen.

You may have to tweak the above code to work in your situation, but this is my best guess without seeing your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response John. But from what I understand from your algorithm, wouldnt it be valid only if the covered area was a square?